# Why does this Mongo Aggregation query not result in a properly ordered set?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents that look like the following:

```
{
  user: "D1D2A08B-7242-4415-BA4F-442B18DBD2ED-2463-00000074A82D0518",
  language: "Cantonese",
  imageFileName: "01D28C90-DB71-40E2-96A2-A934ABC54815-2695-0000043BD1ECAB22",
  audioFileName: "76CD717B-1A57-412C-8973-3518D72B45AD-8996-000008855B90D78A",
  date: ISODate("2013-04-04T18:24:25.753Z"),
  correct: 1,
  _id: ObjectId("515dc559cd9d87de5a000018")
}
```

The following query performs an aggregation that I expect would be ordered by the ISODate element:

```
var getUserStats = function(user, language, callback) {
    var guessCollection = db.collection('Guesses');
    guessCollection.aggregate(
  { $match: {
    user: user,
    language: language,
  }},
  { $sort: {
    date: 1
  }},
  { $project : {
        user : 1,
        language : 1,
        year : { $year: '$date' },
        month : { $month: '$date' },
        day : { $dayOfMonth: '$date'},
        correct : 1,
        guesses : 1
    } },
  { $group : {
        _id : { year: "$year", month: "$month", day: "$day" },
        correct : { $sum : "$correct" },
        guesses: { $sum : 1 }
    } }
, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
    callback(err, result);
});
```

Here's a sample query result:

```
[{
        _id: {
            year: 2013,
            month: 6,
            day: 8
        },
        correct: 11,
        guesses: 17
    }, {
        _id: {
            year: 2013,
            month: 6,
            day: 7
        },
        correct: 11,
        guesses: 15
    }, {
        _id: {
            year: 2013,
            month: 6,
            day: 5
        },
        correct: 35,
        guesses: 48
    }, {
        _id: {
            year: 2013,
            month: 6,
            day: 6
        },
        correct: 69,
        guesses: 96
    }, {
        _id: {
            year: 2013,
            month: 5,
            day: 25
        },
        correct: 2,
        guesses: 3
        ...
```

As you can see, the results of the query are not ordered by date.  Can someone suggest what I may have done incorrectly?

Comment: A group can be unordered, you need a sort after

Comment: I think you're probably correct.  But when I do the following after the group it still does not order the results: { $sort: {
    year: 1, month: 1, day: 1
  }}

Comment: try sorting by _id, MongoDB should be able to sort by the object

Comment: That worked.  Thanks very much.  Would you like to submit an answer for me to accept?

Comment: why are you turning the date into three separate fields?  Why not $project just dropping the hour/minute/etc. to truncate it to day granularity?  You are then aggregating by a single field which remains of type ISODate.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Maybe you can expand that, I am unsure how you can split the date out and then reform it without the time, I thought ISODate() requires a time segment

Comment: See how I do it here: http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/03/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework.html

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Ah I never knew that! Though I wish there was a simpler way of doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group can be unordered. What you can do to sort it correctly is do another sort on the `_id` after you have grouped.